# Queries on using REST API as an Amazon S3 Proxy in API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-api-gateway

I have a use case where I have to upload a large file in the S3. I am planning to do so creating a REST API as an Amazon S3 proxy in API gateway.

I have some queries regarding the same
1. Is it possible to upload a file more than 10 MB? Is the size of the file restricted due to the payload size of API Gateway ?

2. Is there any other mechanism to fetch the bucket name other than fetching it from URL request param aa it is currently being done in most examples ?

Comment: Max size for payload is 10 MB so can't upload more than that directly through api gateway. Can return pre-signed url for your user/app to upload to s3 directly.

Comment: [AWS API Gateway limits](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/limits.html) - I don't think you will be able to have a payload support for more than 10 MB